# Who is at fault right turn into u turner?

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic, accident, car

This is in the UK, where we drive on the left.

We were stopped at T-Junction waiting to turn right (crossing over lane).

Parked on the lane into which we were turning was a car, parked facing the traffic.

Just as we pulled out, the parked car pulled out of its spot and performed a u turn.

So we manouvered, by turning right and they manouvered by starting contraflow and executing u-turn.

We actually did not collide, but I was curious as to who would've been liable.

I think the video will explain the scenario better –
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Am5ZeHETxN7g5L0NqlR1Q_Tg4MI6kA?e=37qcHI

Comment: This link looks **very** suspicious!

Comment: it isn't, it is my one drive!, but happy to upload another metod that you suggest. @Trish

Comment: Even some written description could be helpful. Were you turning in an intersection that had stop lights? Stop signs? Was the other car parked on the side you were turning into or the other side? They were performing a u-turn from a parked position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly the other car had been stopped on the wrong side of the road, and pulled out without indicating.

[image]

However, they were on the major road which you were turning right onto, and they had their headlights already lit, and they began to move before you fully committed. Had you noticed that, you could have stopped and waited.

You don't have right of way when turning into a major road. You didn't even slow down enough to make a proper assessment of the junction. If I were an insurance assessor I would say that you failed to take into account a potential hazard.

---

But what blame does the other vehicle have? Their view of you was obscured at first by a passing vehicle. Both those vehicles have their lights on, yet I can't see any illumination from your own lights on the wall opposite or on the side of the other vehicle as you approach it. Were your lights on? It is raining with poor visibility, and perhaps the other car didn't even see you.

I would advise using your lights, and driving with more caution and better observation.